# How to replace or cover a hole left by kitchen fan that vented to nowhere?

Tags: kitchens, exhaust-fan, replacement

I removed my old exhaust fan, and in my naivety I disposed of it prematurely, thinking that I would be able to find a drop in replacement. Either my Google-fu is failing me, they don't make the size fan anymore, or it was a hack to begin with.

[image]
[image]

A couple of notes about this opening:

- The size of the opening is roughly 9"x 9"
- It looks like there is some sort of cover or door at the very top, and it appears that the cover is designed to open, but I don't know how to confirm this.

**My questions are**:

1. Can anyone provide any information on this type of opening?
2. Is there a fan that I can install in this opening? If so, what type? All of the kitchen/bath exhaust fans I've seen are made to install into a round duct coming in from the side. If so, what type of fan should I be looking for?
3. If not, What are the alternatives beyond a custom grille to cover it up?

Comment: There used to be square desktop type fans of about that size, maybe it was a hack at one time.  Had a small fan, when needed to replace, could only find a 12x12.

Comment: @crip659 What was there seemed to resemble an industrial type fan, no guard/shroud over the blades.

Comment: Push on the cover - likely it opens easily and is thus just the flap that prevents wind from blowing into the kitchen. Probably need to open up the ceiling a bit more, take out the sheet metal box, and connect up a new fan to the (likely) round duct heading to the great outdoors.

Comment: @JonCuster interesting, I'll try that; For some reason I tried _pulling_ it open haha

Comment: Could be possible that the fan you had was not marketed as an exhaust fan.  Google is usually good, only if you put in the right words to find what you want.

Comment: @crip659 oh it's _entirely_ possible; just now I came across _shutter exhaust fans_ that seem to be a possible match.

Comment: you will likely have to rip out the metal case to install a new fan; joy. I think most square fans are slightly larger, which means you'll have to slightly extend the hole. That's work, but it's better than having a too big hole.